# gcloud app deploy fails: permission denied for [ID] from request [URL]

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app.yaml, google-iam

I'm trying to deploy my React app to Google Cloud App Engine using `gcloud app deploy` from my computer. This worked fine last weekend, and before.

I get the following output:

```
$ gcloud app deploy .
Services to deploy:

descriptor:      [REDACTED]
source:          [REDACTED]
target project:  [REDACTED]
target service:  [REDACTED]
target version:  [REDACTED]
target url:      [REDACTED]


Do you want to continue (Y/n)?

Beginning deployment of service [default]...
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Uploading 0 files to Google Cloud Storage                ═╣
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build 53d56399-b9ac-4471-8ecb-e06e557523fa status: FAILURE.
Build error details: Build error details not available..
Check the build log for errors: https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/builds/53d56399-b9ac-4471-8ecb-e06e557523fa?project=995586812495
```

Following the link in the build log takes me to a Cloud Build log in Google Cloud Console. Below is the last section of that log. There is way more log above this point, but it seems to have gone ok.

```
Step #1 - "builder": INFO rm_node_modules took 0 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO starting: checking_cached_packages_json_layer
Step #1 - "builder": DEBUG Checking cache for cache_key 75e33f825bb6b991a429a251df57d5c82f04475bb87972004100213e6e245c4d
Step #1 - "builder": INFO checking_cached_packages_json_layer took 0 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO build process for FTL image took 0 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO full build took 0 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": Traceback (most recent call last):
Step #1 - "builder": File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
Step #1 - "builder": "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
Step #1 - "builder": File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
Step #1 - "builder": exec code in run_globals
Step #1 - "builder": File "/ftl-v0.9.0.par/__main__.py", line 65, in <module>
Step #1 - "builder": File "/ftl-v0.9.0.par/__main__.py", line 54, in main
Step #1 - "builder": File "/ftl-v0.9.0.par/__main__/ftl/node/builder.py", line 81, in Build
Step #1 - "builder": File "/ftl-v0.9.0.par/__main__/ftl/node/layer_builder.py", line 60, in BuildLayer
Step #1 - "builder": File "/ftl-v0.9.0.par/__main__/ftl/common/cache.py", line 113, in Get
Step #1 - "builder": File "/ftl-v0.9.0.par/__main__/ftl/common/cache.py", line 137, in _getEntry
Step #1 - "builder": File "/ftl-v0.9.0.par/__main__/ftl/common/cache.py", line 152, in _getLocalEntry
Step #1 - "builder": File "/ftl-v0.9.0.par/__main__/ftl/common/cache.py", line 175, in getEntryFromCreds
Step #1 - "builder": File "/ftl-v0.9.0.par/containerregistry/client/v2_2/docker_image_.py", line 279, in exists
Step #1 - "builder": File "/ftl-v0.9.0.par/containerregistry/client/v2_2/docker_image_.py", line 293, in manifest
Step #1 - "builder": File "/ftl-v0.9.0.par/containerregistry/client/v2_2/docker_image_.py", line 250, in _content
Step #1 - "builder": File "/ftl-v0.9.0.par/containerregistry/client/v2_2/docker_http_.py", line 364, in Request
Step #1 - "builder": containerregistry.client.v2_2.docker_http_.V2DiagnosticException: response: {'status': '403', 'content-length': '288', 'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'server': 'Docker Registry', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'docker-distribution-api-version': 'registry/2.0', 'cache-control': 'private', 'date': 'Sun, 11 Nov 2018 12:13:02 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'content-type': 'application/json'}
Step #1 - "builder": Permission denied for "75e33f825bb6b991a429a251df57d5c82f04475bb87972004100213e6e245c4d" from request "/v2/apparat-web/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d/node-cache/manifests/75e33f825bb6b991a429a251df57d5c82f04475bb87972004100213e6e245c4d". : None
Finished Step #1 - "builder"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/gae-runtimes/nodejs8_app_builder:nodejs8_8_12_0_20180928_RC00" failed: exit status 1
```

As you can see, the error message is

```
Permission denied for "75e33f825bb6b991a429a251df57d5c82f04475bb87972004100213e6e245c4d" from request "/v2/apparat-web/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d/node-cache/manifests/75e33f825bb6b991a429a251df57d5c82f04475bb87972004100213e6e245c4d". : None
Finished Step #1 - "builder"
```

I don't understand what it's telling me is wrong. I am not able to map the 75e33-ID to a user account, and even if I am, what is the resource it's claiming is denying permissions and what can I do about it? It seems like google cloud internals to me and I have no clue how to proceed.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

#### Things I've tried

- `gcloud auth revoke` and `gcloud auth login` to ensure I'm logged in with the correct account for the current project
- `gcloud config list` and verified the current `project` is correct.
- When I run `gcloud app deploy` I've also verified that the project information is correct when it prompts for confirmation before performing the deploy
- Verified my user account is (still) added with correct Roles in Google Cloud Console IAM

Comment: To me this appears suspect: `Uploading 0 files to Google Cloud Storage`. The build failure could be just a side effect of it. Try increasing the deployment verbosity to see if you can figure out why no files are uploaded.

Answer (score 10):

I had a very similar problem (identical, except that I was on python37 standard).
The logs had this in it:

```
Step #1 - "builder": Permission denied for "d7dab0ac46167635bcee11cda0f4dbd2963e1cfeaf021404fa295f99c37070e3" from request "/v2/<project-id>/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d/python-cache/manifests/d7dab0ac46167635bcee11cda0f4dbd2963e1cfeaf021404fa295f99c37070e3". : None
```

It's actually a GAE configuration problem. In my case it was that I deleted the database (moved it to a different service) and disabled billing.

Shockingly, I solved it by simply re-enabling billing for the project...

Comment: Worked for me too.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error message, and turned out to be billing related.

If you are going from free credits to credit card-based billing, you need to manually go in and 'activate' that paid billing, even if your CC is already on file.

Answer (score -1):

You've got the same error as me ... in your traces :

`Step #1 - "builder": Traceback (most recent call last):
Step #1 - "builder": File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
Step #1 - "builder": "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
Step #1 - "builder": File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code`

Like me, you have an older version (py27) which seems to break the full chain
I'm searchine too
Can't upload a new py37 version ;-(

Comment: The gcloud cli tool throws an error if I use any other python version than 2.7